# Rescale a character to fill a complete A4 page

Tags: fontsize, characters

I am maybe looking for the wrong keywords.
But I do not find any answer about how to scale a letter to fill the entire A4 page.

My first intuitive step was to use the option `scale` of the package `geometry` but this failed due to the margins. Argument: `scale` works properly only for values below one if I am right.

Currently I do not want to use `tikz`, as I thought it must work much simpler than scaling it graphically.

Comment: You could use the graphicx package and `\resizebox{!}{0.9\textheight}{\Huge L}`

Comment: I would say on A4 pages the width is the limiting factor. Hence `\resizebox{!}{0.9\textwidth}{L}` was what I preferred as I wrote each character on a standard (non-landscape) single page.

Comment: When the char gets too height for the page you can get empty pages. It is to large you "only" get overfull messages. But you can always measure the char and then choose which value is best.

Comment: My strategy for this is to print it out normal size on an empty page using `standalone` to crop the PDF to the size of the letter(s).  Then in my PDF viewer I print it out scaling it up to fit.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: I would say this strategy sounds much like what UlrikeFischer provided in her comment except that you would print each letter separately? Hence this would mean more work and files... ;)

Comment: @strpeter I think it could handle a multi-page document with one letter per page.  I haven't experimented, though.  The point is to allow the PDF viewer to do the scaling, not TeX.

Comment: @LoopSpace: If you let the PDF viewer do the job, it gets somewhat ambiguous. Every viewer has different settings... Do you agree?

Comment: @strpeter Does that matter?  (If it's true, which I'm not convinced of as scaling is a fairly straightforward transformation.)  I wouldn't say it was ambiguous though since if you like how your PDF viewer does it then you've nothing to worry about.  So you can optimise it for your PDF viewer/printer and not worry about the fact that others might do something slightly different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found some kind of an answer in German at a [short LyX introduction](http://lyx.atspace.org/#23).

The implementation of this as a MWE could look like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%almost vertically centered (and flexible in horzontal extension:
\usepackage[lmargin=0cm,rmargin=0cm,tmargin=7cm,bmargin=7cm]{geometry} 
\newfont{\tmpfont}{cmr17 scaled 32768}{\tmpfont }
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\tmpfont\centering
L\clearpage
E\clearpage
T\clearpage
T\clearpage
E\clearpage
R\clearpage
S\clearpage

\end{document}
```

### Remark

The value `32768=2^{15}` can not be increased by `1`, otherwise I get the compiler error message:

```
Illegal magnification has been changed to 1000 (32769).
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.4 \newfont{\tmpfont}{cmr17 scaled 32769}
                                          {\tmpfont }
```

I am not clear why the magnification is limited by 2^{15} - which is an effective scaling of a factor about 32. At least this magnification satisfied me and answered my question.

### Following Ulrike's hint

This approach does not lead to troubles with scaling factors. MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newfont{\tmpfont}{cmr17}{\tmpfont }
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\tmpfont\centering
\topskip0pt
\vspace*{\fill}
\resizebox{!}{0.9\textwidth}{L}
\vspace*{\fill}\clearpage\topskip0pt\vspace*{\fill}
\resizebox{!}{0.9\textwidth}{E}
\vspace*{\fill}\clearpage\topskip0pt\vspace*{\fill}
\resizebox{!}{0.9\textwidth}{T}
\vspace*{\fill}\clearpage\topskip0pt\vspace*{\fill}
\resizebox{!}{0.9\textwidth}{T}
\vspace*{\fill}\clearpage\topskip0pt\vspace*{\fill}
\resizebox{!}{0.9\textwidth}{E}
\vspace*{\fill}\clearpage\topskip0pt\vspace*{\fill}
\resizebox{!}{0.9\textwidth}{R}
\vspace*{\fill}\clearpage\topskip0pt\vspace*{\fill}
\resizebox{!}{0.9\textwidth}{S}
\vspace*{\fill}

\end{document}
```

Comment: “scaled” is based on the tex `\magnification` mechanism; knuth (p.60 of the tex book) says the scale factor should be no larger than 32768.  no-one would deny that 32769 is as much an integer as 32768; but knuth surely had some programming reason to limit the parameter; it's often difficult to see why such things appear, but we should remember that we're programming in an immensely more powerful environment than knuth was, and back then some restrictions, that seem ridiculous today, were run-of-the-mill stuff.

Comment: `\fontsize{1.2\textheight}{1.2\textheight}\selectfont
L` or `cmr17 at 29cm` would work too (you need a scalable font so load fix-cm or lmodern), but it is more difficult to find the "correct" scaling value.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I would appreciate if you provided a new proper answer. It makes no sense if I try to write down what you ment.