# How to increase the size of the mathscr font

Tags: fonts, fontsize

Im on an book report class document and I want a extremely large `\mathscr{T}` covering a considerable portion of a page. I know how to do this without the \mathscr font but as soon as I add the font, the size of the letter is reduced. How can I achive a humongous `\mathscr{T}`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rescale a character to fill a complete A4 page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183104/rescale-a-character-to-fill-a-complete-a4-page) (Ultike's comment: `\resizebox{!}{0.9\textheight}{\Huge L}`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would have saved time if you would have provided an MWE (I had to reverse-engineer that you probably use the `mathrsfs` package).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}

\resizebox{!}{0.9\textwidth}{$\mathscr{T}$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you use Unicode fonts, you can use the `Scale=` option (here, 40, arbitrarily).

It would more practical to set it as an ornament letter, though, rather than as part of an actual equation.

[image: script T]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TexGyrePagella-Math}
\newfontface\fscr{TexGyreSchola-Math}[Colour=red,Scale=40]
\newcommand\fscrT{{\fscr }}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\fscrT\kern-20em\llap{$x^2+y^2=z^2$}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.fd` file for `rsfs` has only fixed sizes, as was normal in olden times:

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{rsfs}{\skewchar\font127 }
\DeclareFontShape{U}{rsfs}{m}{n}{%
   <5> <6> rsfs5
   <7> rsfs7
   <8> <9> <10> <10.95> <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> rsfs10
}{}
```

Nowadays, the font is available in Type1 format, so arbitrarily scalable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{rsfs}{\skewchar\font127 }
\DeclareFontShape{U}{rsfs}{m}{n}{%
   <-6.5> rsfs5
   <6.5-8.5> rsfs7
   <8.5-> rsfs10
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\fontsize{256}{0}\usefont{U}{rsfs}{m}{n}T
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can add kerning in order to cope with the fact that the character extends beyond its bounding box on the right.